# Spring MVC Test with RestTemplate: Generic collection fails (even with ParameterizedTypeReference)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-test-mvc

I am working with Spring Framework `4.3.1`

I have the following domain class

```
@XmlRootElement(name="persona")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id","nombre","apellido","fecha"})
public class Persona implements Serializable {

    @XmlElement(name="id")
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    ....
```

Where each getter has the `@XmlElement` and `@JsonProperty` annotations.
I am working with `JAXB2` and `Jackson2`

I have the following too:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="collection")
public class GenericCollection<T> {

    private Collection<T> collection;

    public GenericCollection(){

    }

    public GenericCollection(Collection<T> collection){
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    @XmlElement(name="item")
    @JsonProperty("collection")
    public Collection<T> getCollection() {
        return collection;
    }

    public void setCollection(Collection<T> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
      for(Object object : collection){
        builder.append("[");
        builder.append(object.toString());
        builder.append("]");
      }
      return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

About Testing, the many `@Test`s methods working through `Spring MVC Test` work fine. The `@Controller` and `@RestController` work how is expected.

**Note**: I can test the CRUD scenarios, it about the `HTTP methods` such as `POST`, `PUT`, `GET` and `DELETE`. Therefore I am able to get one entity and a collection of entities.

**Note**: from the previous note, all works working around the `XML` and `JSON` formats.

Now trying to do testing through the `RestTemplate` how a kind of programmatic client, it **only** *fails* for collections. With the following:

```
@Before
public void setUp(){
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new MockMvcClientHttpRequestFactory(mockMvc));

    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.marshallingMessageConverter());
    converters.add(httpMessageConverterConfig.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(converters);
    System.out.println("converters.size():" + converters.size());
}
```

I can confirm `converters.size()` always prints `2`

The following is for XML and JSON

```
@Test
public void findAllXmlTest(){

    RequestEntity<Void> requestEntity = RestControllerSupport_.createRequestEntityForGet(uri, retrieveURI);

    ParameterizedTypeReference<GenericCollection<Persona>> parameterizedTypeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<GenericCollection<Persona>>(){};
    ResponseEntity<GenericCollection<Persona>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, parameterizedTypeReference);

    assertThat(responseEntity, notNullValue());

    assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
    assertThat(responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType(), is(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML) );

    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getClass(), is(GenericCollection.class));
    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getCollection(), is(personas));

}

@Test
public void findAllJsonTest(){

    RequestEntity<Void> requestEntity = RestControllerSupport_.createRequestEntityForGet(uri, retrieveURI);

    ParameterizedTypeReference<GenericCollection<Persona>> parameterizedTypeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<GenericCollection<Persona>>(){};
    ResponseEntity<GenericCollection<Persona>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, parameterizedTypeReference);

    assertThat(responseEntity, notNullValue());

    assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode(), is(HttpStatus.OK));
    assertThat(responseEntity.getHeaders().getContentType(), is(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8) );

    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody(), notNullValue());
    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getClass(), is(GenericCollection.class));
    assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getCollection(), is(personas));

}
```

**Note:** observe I am using `ParameterizedTypeReference` for both scenarios.

For JSON it works.

But for XML I get:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [com.manuel.jordan.controller.support.GenericCollection<com.manuel.jordan.domain.Persona>] and content type [application/xml]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:109)
```

What is wrong or missing?

Comment: Manuel can you share your pom? and configuration

Comment: I am working with `Gradle`, just shared the `Spring Framework` configuration about dependencies. Let me know what specific section you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem that you use `MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` which isn't `GenericHttpMessageConverter`, like it is expected for the `ParameterizedTypeReference` in the `HttpMessageConverterExtractor`:

```
if (messageConverter instanceof GenericHttpMessageConverter) {
                GenericHttpMessageConverter<?> genericMessageConverter =
                        (GenericHttpMessageConverter<?>) messageConverter;
                if (genericMessageConverter.canRead(this.responseType, null, contentType)) {
```

The `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is that one.

So, I suggest you to try with `Jaxb2CollectionHttpMessageConverter`.

Comment: Interesting, I will do a research about `Jaxb2CollectionHttpMessageConverter`. It is interesting. I have almost the same code  (previous version for other project) working with `Spock Framework` and using this line `responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, GenericCollection.class)` and works. Sadly that line does not compile in Java